# What foods do not need a Pesach hechsher?

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, passover, hechsher-certification

Which foods are kosher for Pesach with only a "year-round" hechsher, or with no hechsher at all?

Comment: No points for water or fresh (*peelable) fruits and vegetables.

Comment: For purchase before or during pesach?

Comment: 3 more items: http://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/milk/ http://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/missing-from-the-directory/ http://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/salt/ But I think posting two answers is enough.

Comment: @Ariel I think you can combine multiple things in one answer.

Comment: No one else took em, so I combined everything into one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extra Virgin olive oil. [Source](http://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/extra-virgin-olive-oil/)

> All extra virgin olive oils are Kosher for Passover, as long as it bears the OU symbol
>
> All other oils (including olive oil) require a reliable Kosher for Passover certification to be consumed on Passover.

Milk [Source](http://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/milk/)

> Milk contains added vitamins that contain a slight chometz risk. Therefore it is best to purchase milk before Passover at which time chometz can be nullified (batel).

Regular Ground Coffee [Source](http://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/coffee/)

> All regular ground coffees are acceptable for Passover use when bearing an OU.
>
> Decaffeinated coffee:
> Coffee is often decaffeinated by means of ethyl acetate, which is derived from either kitniyot or chometz. Therefore, decaffeinated coffees are not acceptable for Passover unless specifically listed in the section of the Passover guide which contains items that to not require Passover certification.
>
> Instant coffees often contain maltodextrin, which is derived from either corn (kitniyot) or wheat (chometz). Therefore, all instant coffees require special Passover certification unless explicitly mentioned in the section of the Passover guide which contains items that to not require Passover certification.

Salt [Source](http://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/salt/)

> Salt that is iodized by means of a corn derivative is (kitniyos) and therefore iodized salt requires Passover certification. Un-iodized salt does not require Passover certification, nor does sea salt.

Comment: Nice.  Consider turning this in to a community wiki so we can just assemble a large list.

Comment: Coffee is [very limited](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/121802#.VRF_WvnF9WU), and even that is [controversial](http://www.ok.org/isitkosher/coffee-kosher-passover/) - see [footnote 2](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/coffee_and_tea_pesach.php) here for some of the concerns.

Comment: Why does this make sense "All extra virgin olive oils are Kosher for Passover, as long as it bears the OU symbol"?  All Extra Virgin Olive Oil is kosher with no hechsher.  Is the OU just trying to promote the use of its hechsher?

Answer (score 0):

If you download the CRC kashrus app for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rocketouch.CRCKosher2013&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dcrc+kashrut+app&pcampaignid=APPU_1_woIRVaH3I4inyQSw8YH4Dw) or (I assume) for [iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/crc-kosher/id397991421?mt=8), there is a yearly update which includes a Passover section that has a large list of foods and tells which ones need reliable certification for Passover and which do not.